# How to group by 3 columns and given count in Python DataFrames

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, count

I have 3 columns, I want to do a count based on the common values in the 3 columns for eg

```
Dataframe is
Date     Name    SoldItem
15-Jul    Joe     TV
15-Jul    Joe     Fridge
15-Jul    Joe     Washing Machine
15-Jul    Joe     TV
15-Jul    Joe     Fridge
15-Jul    Mary    Chair
15-Jul    Mary    Fridge
16-Jul    Joe     Fridge
16-Jul    Joe     Fridge
16-Jul    Tim     Washing Machine
17-Jul    Joe     Washing Machine
17-Jul    Jimmy   Washing Machine
17-Jul    Joe     Washing Machine
17-Jul    Joe     Washing Machine

And final output should be

Date      Name   SoldItem       Count
15-Jul     Joe    TV              2
           Joe    Fridge          2
           Joe    Washing Machine 1
          Mary    Chair           1
          Mary    Fridge          1
16-Jul     Joe    Fridge          2
           Tim    Washing Machine 1
17-Jul     Joe    Washing Machine 3
         Jimmy    Washing Machine 1
```

I tried below code, but it works only on 2 columns

```
df.groupby(["Date", "Name"]).size()  

provides like

Date      Name   
15-Jul     Joe    5
          Mary    2
16-Jul     Joe    2
           Tim    1
17-Jul     Joe    3
         Jimmy    1
When i use the below
df.groupby(["Date", "Name", "SoldItem"]).size()  

it throws the error

ValueError: Length of passed values is xx, index implies 0
```

This is how i load the dataframe

```
   fields = ['Date', 'Name', 'SoldItem']
   df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
   df_grp = df.groupby(["Date", "Name"]).size()
print df_grp
```

So would appreciate if you could kindly advise how I can group based on 3 values and provide the count. Much appreciated in advance. Also am new to Python.

Comment: do you have any missing values in your dataset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some **missing data** in your dataset and that's why you are getting that Error. you probably want to look if there are any missing values because your code should be fine.

The problem are the NA (missing values) entries in your dataset. Each row in your dataset has at least one NA in that Column ( that's my own opinion). When you apply .groupby to NA entries, it wouldn't know how to group NAs so it removes them, leaving an empty result (length 0).

take a look here for References: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html

below are examples that I copied from this Github link
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23050

### Example of simple Code which will produce the same Error

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x', 'y'], 'B': [np.nan, np.nan]})
>>> df.groupby(['A', 'B']).size()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1227, in size
    result = self.grouper.size()
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 233, in size
    dtype='int64')
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 249, in __init__
    .format(val=len(data), ind=len(index)))
ValueError: Length of passed values is 2, index implies 0
```

Comment: If you are going to copy someone's answer at least give them credit: [answer](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23050#issuecomment-428002681). Your answer is not quite appropriate as the situation is different. But you are right that this is probably due to NA values.

Comment: I already copied all the references here.If I want to stole an answer than I wouldnt post here a reference from where i took that

Comment: Thanks this comment pointed me in the right direction. I replaced the null values with N.A and my code worked. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

@user3423407
I saved your data as csv file and processed it as below.

```py
import pandas as pd
fields = ['Date', 'Name', 'SoldItem']
df = pd.read_csv('PathToCSVFile.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
df_grp = df.groupby(["Date", "Name", "SoldItem"]).size()
print(df_grp)
```

Got the output as below. I did not do any changes in your code. For the example dataset it works. Is it that it does not work for larger dataset?
[image: Output as I see it]